# My player sprite is flipping outside of its box collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, 2d-games

[image]I wrote a script that flips the sprite depending on which direction you are moving. I realized though that when the sprite flips it flips way to far on the x axis, and completely outside the box collider. causing the player to appear like it's glitching during movement. Also once the box collider hits one side of the terrain it causes the player to no longer be able to move forward. This is what my sprite looks like when it's flipped, why won't it just flip inside the box collider.

I thought maybe adjusting the pivot point would help, didn't work though

Comment: because what you flipped does not have a pivot point of the middle of the sprite, so its rotating round the pivot not what you expected

Comment: can I move the pivot point? how do I do that, I heard that wasn't possible but idk

Comment: well you can place it in an empty and then move the child underneath..... to make the pivot where you need it